# error "Only one file name allowed" Dmenu + Vim on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vim

Attempting dmenu with vim on ec2/ubuntu. Git is installed.

Follwing the steps in here: http://leafo.net/posts/using_dmenu_to_open_quickly.html

Any idea why I'm getting this error in vim?

```
Error detected while processing function DmenuOpen:
line 5:
E172: Only one file name allowed: tabe dmenu: cannot open display
```

Comment: Was using straight vim through putty on Windows. Didn't realize X Server was required for dmenu, or what's required to get this working in putty. Other terminals come with X Server, but so far they've been too sluggish to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is in your environment: `cannot open display`. Dmenu needs access to your X server to show its completion menu. In your terminal, you need to define something like

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

You can check whether that is working by executing `dmenu` (or `xclock`, or `gvim`, or any other X app).

---

Second, the command in the Vim integration

```
execute a:cmd . " " . fname
```

is missing proper escaping; that's why you get the E172 error. To handle all kinds of file names, use

```
execute a:cmd . " " . fnameescape(fname)
```

To top it off, a little bit of defensive programming would have prevented all this. After `system()`, it is good practice to check `v:shell_error` whether the external command actually succeeded.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can't execute dmenu after running the export line in terminal. looking for something else..

Comment: ah, as I'm running this remotely on ec2 , through a terminal, I'm starting to understand dmenu has need of extra magics? I need to learn how to turn on x display so it works with putty?

Comment: When you're on Windows (using PuTTY), you have to install an X Server, e.g. _Cygwin-X_, which is part of Cygwin. It's a major software install, though. It would be way easier if you were on Linux.

Comment: I'm coming to understand this. It works through MobaXterm and gvim but it's ridiculously slow. Thanks, Linux would be better in many ways..

Comment: Thanks! was having issues with lawrencium, and my .vim is in a folder with a space.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, your function is passing multiple filenames or what Vim understands as multiple filenames to `:tabe` or `:e` which can only deal with *one* filename.

Maybe files with spaces in their name?

Replace

```
execute a:cmd . " " . fname
```

with

```
echo fname
```

to see what is passed to `:tabe`.

Comment: "dmenu: cannot open display" pops up, only. Perhaps I'm missing something about echo, shouldn't it show inside vim?

Comment: `echo` should echo the filtered output of `dmenu` but it looks like `dmenu` can't run anyway. Because `dmenu` outputs `dmenu: cannot open display`, Vim tries to do `:tabe dmenu: cannot open display` which obviously can't work. You must investigate what is causing `dmenu` to fail. Or, that's what I understand. Do you even get the file listing?